# ElasticSearch - Comparing the title of documents in two indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to ElasticSearch and want to see if something is possible before I continue.

I have two Indexes (it doesn't have to be, they could be structured differently).

For simplicity, these indexes have documents with a title in.

i.e

```
{
    "_index": "source1",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 2,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "title": "Defendant: SMITH, JOHN. Charge: Murder."
    }
}

{
    "_index": "source2",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "title": "SMITH, John Edward"
    }
}
```

Each index will have around 20-30 thousand rows, and there will be about 6 indexes in all.

I need to compare ALL documents across ALL indexes and find out which ones are most likely to match based on the words in the title (Mainly looking at the name in the title).

Basically I need to do a search without knowing the search terms.

I will be using NEST with ElasticSearch. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: _most likely to match based on the words in the title_ - Case-sensitive/insensitive? Should words undergo stemming and lemmatization? Should synonyms be taken into account? Is there some threshold for relevancy scoring? A simple (naive) first approach could be to use a More Like This query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way is to invert your index name with your type name.

The type `document` is the same for both index, so put all documents in the same index, with different types. Then you could perform your request.

Comment: My thoughts were I would have to put all documents in to one index with a type classifier but I still am not sure on the rest. i.e how to match relevance on the title.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you don't know how to make your request ? If it's this, just do a match query like [this for example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-filter-context.html)

Comment: But I don't know what terms I am matching on, I need to match the relevance of one document title to the other.

As above. "Basically I need to do a search without knowing the search terms"

Comment: read about more like this query in elasticsearch. If that doesn't help, let us know why and we might get your question better